# Сортировка массива из структур по данным из членов этой структуры

Tags: c++, сортировка, vector

есть структура

```
struct user{
    int id;
    int reiting;
};
```

и есть вектор из этих структур. Как отсортировать вектор чтобы элементы расположились в порядке возрастания переменной reiting?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например, так:

```
vector<user> v;
...
sort(v.begin(),v.end(),[](const user& a, const user& b){ return a.reiting<b.reiting;});
```